# PoA, POW and POS blockchains

Tags: blockchain

I know Bitcoin runs on a POW (Proof of work) concept and that there is a side chain of Ethereum using PoA but other than that what other blockchains/crypto currencies run using  these or different protocols?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://hackernoon.com/a-hitchhikers-guide-to-consensus-algorithms-d81aae3eb0e3) you can read the difference between consensus algorithms, how do they work and who uses them.  There are more consensus algorithms (Proof-of-Importance in *NEM*, Proof-of-Elapsed-Time and other).

---

[**POS**](https://blockonomi.com/proof-stake-cryptocurrencies/)

- DASH
- LISK
- NEO
- PIVX
- OKCASH
- STRATIS
- and more

---

[**POW**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cryptocurrencies)

- BTC
- BCH
- ETH
- LTC
- DOGE

---

**POA**

- VeChain
- Kovan
- POA Network